# Droprate % of Prideful gear from Celestials?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

As PvP season 15 is dawning upon us, Blizzard has decided to give us a chance at next seasons gear by letting us do Celestials and getting a chance for the gear.

What are the drop rates of the items from these?

Comment: why the -1 to my question? it's valid.

Comment: Wowhead should be your first stop for anything related to items in WoW.

Comment: That's your personal preference to solving the issue , I like to try and involve a community into my problems & work together to fix a common goal , it's more fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chance of getting a drop from Celestials is expected to be about 15% - [Source](http://wowpedia.org/Personal_loot#Personal_Loot)

Then you have to look at [what possible loot you can get for your faction/spec/class](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=71952).

For my alliance Blood DK that leaves 12 pieces of posible loot, ignore the [Celestial Treasure Box](http://www.wowhead.com/item=104272) I would get if I was unlucky.

That means that each piece of loot has 1.25% chance of dropping (1/12 * 15%).

Since only 10 of them are pvp pieces the chance for my Blood DK getting a piece of the new pvp loot is 12.5%